# Android ListView throwning NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview

I have an android app that gets an HTTP response from a webservice, which I process into an array of strings. I than try to display those strings in a ListView. they do not need to be clicked for any action, just displayed and be scroll-able. 
When ran, Everything gets done ok, but when I try to scroll down beyond the amount of items that i have to show (because there are no more strings to display on list) I get a NullPointerException. Obviously I must be doing something wrong. 
I don't quite get it. I've written a similar example as a test and it works just fine. the list in the example just scrolls and stops when there are no more items to show. The only difference I can think of is that on the original app the array gets created on a thread, and than the thread runs a runnable using a handler to display the list on the gui.

when the thread that fetches the strings and orders them to the array to display finishes, he runs this code using a handler:

```
    scoreList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scorelist);
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,scoreResult);
    scoreList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

than the app crashes when trying to scroll lower than the bottom. this is the error from adb logcat:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(  864): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  864): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  864): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromRes
ource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdap
ter.java:323)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsList
View.java:1294)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListVi
ew.java:1727)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.jav
a:652)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java
:623)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(
AbsListView.java:2944)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsLi
stView.java:2065)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView
.java:3315)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.jav
a:3766)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(Vie
wGroup.java:897)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(Vie
wGroup.java:936)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(Vie
wGroup.java:936)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(Vie
wGroup.java:936)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$
DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.
superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activ
ity.java:2086)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$
DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.
java:1785)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
21)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  864):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

W/ActivityManager(   59):   Force finishing activity memo.ori.friend/.Highscores

W/ActivityManager(   59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4503fed0 memo
.ori.friend/.Highscores}
W/WindowManager(   59): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
W/ActivityManager(   59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
W/ActivityManager(   59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{45023af0 memo.
ori.friend/.MemoFriendActivity}
D/dalvikvm(  261): GC_EXPLICIT freed 45 objects / 2128 bytes in 108ms
W/ActivityManager(   59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4503fed0 me
mo.ori.friend/.Highscores}
D/SntpClient(   59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address fami
ly not supported by protocol
I/Process (  864): Sending signal. PID: 864 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(   59): Process memo.ori.friend (pid 864) has died.
I/WindowManager(   59): WIN DEATH: Window{45077ce0 memo.ori.friend/memo.ori.frie
nd.MemoFriendActivity paused=false}
I/WindowManager(   59): WIN DEATH: Window{4507cf60 memo.ori.friend/memo.ori.frie
nd.Highscores paused=false}
I/UsageStats(   59): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already res
umed in memo.ori.friend
W/InputManagerService(   59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notif
ication to pid 864 uid 10044
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(  126): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/SntpClient(   59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address fami
ly not supported by protocol
```

Comment: check the id inside the xml file. List view should have "scorelist" as id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When ran, Everything gets done ok, but when I try to scroll down
>   beyond the amount of items that i have to show (because there are no
>   more strings to display on list) I get a NullPointerException.
>   Obviously I must be doing something wrong.

That exception comes from having `null` values in the list/array(`scoreResult`) that you pass to the `ArrayAdapter`. This is because the `ArrayAdapter` will call, by default,(in it's `getView` method which is responsible for building the list's rows) the `toString` method on each item from the data list if the type of that item isn't a `CharSequence`(you have `String`), to obtain a text representation of that item to show in the row.

So check the `scoreResult` list/array and make sure you don't have `null` values in it. I see you speak of an array, make sure the array is just as big as it needs for the data, if it's bigger than the data you'll have `null` values at its end.

Answer (score 1):

```
request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address fami
ly not supported by protocol
```

pls check what is there, somethig not good.

NullPointerException it is the beginner programmer sign: it doesn't verify the parameters and he write multiple statements in 1 line. In this case I would check the `scoreResult` to not be empty, but at least not null

Comment: Thanks. I believe you are right. scoreResult is filled with values but it is bigger in length than the actuacl values, so the rest of it is null. i bet that's what causing the problem. pretty obvious. Bah. Thanks!